# Problem with number of groups in ROCK alghoritm in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am doing data grouping in python. I was able to group the set seamlessly using the K-modes algorithm and got 4 groups.

Now it tries to do the same using the ROCK algorithm to compare the results. Unfortunately, instead of getting 4 groups, each row is assigned to a separate group.

My dataset has categorical data, so I use the ROCK algorithm, which in turn is made for this.

Here is the code:

```
from pyclustering.cluster.rock import rock;

rules_rock_dataframe = rules_rock_dataframe.astype(float)
rules_rock_dataframe_list = rules_rock_dataframe.values.tolist()
rock = rock(rules_rock_dataframe_list, 2.0, number_clusters=4)
rock.process()

clusters = rock.get_clusters()
print(clusters)
```

I'm transforming a dataset into list because the algorithm doesn't take a dataset as an argument.

As a result, I get 286 groups.
Unfortunately, I don't know where I am making a mistake.

EDIT.
The problem with creating so many groups is because the implemented algorithm uses a Euclidean distance measure to find similarity between data points, which cannot work with categorical data.

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code,data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Images can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Also, refrain from posting links to problem definitions and/or explanations Instead, incorporate the explanation into your question directly.

Comment: Would you show a portion of `rules_rock_dataframe`?